# Access subdomain of ubuntu guest OS on Virtual box from Windows7 host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, subdomain

Using *NAT* and *port forwarding* 8008 to 80 I have managed to access the Ubuntu guest localhost from windows host using URL: `http://localhost:8008`

Now my question is:

I am trying to access **subdomain.localhost** of Ubuntu using url: `http://subdomain.localhost:8008` but i am getting **403 Forbidden** error.
The same URL from the Ubuntu guest is working properly.

> My Ubuntu: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Virtual box: Version 5.2.16 r123759
>   (Qt5.6.2)

*Vbox running as admin from windows*

Answer (score 0):

It is not meaningful to treat the special name [`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) as if it were an ordinary DNS domain name. It isn't. It is [special](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761#section-6.3). It is not surprising that attempting to use localhost in this way leads to weird results that are difficult to predict or understand.

You may find it more useful to solve your problem using a different approach

See [Add subdomain to localhost URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19016553/477035)

Comment: I tried your link, but the result is the same. i think it's a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

> SOLVED

just updated in the virtual host file

from:

```
   <Directory "/home/amit/buildkit/build/dd47">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        <IfModule mod_authz_host.c>
            Require local granted
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```

to:

```
   <Directory "/home/amit/buildkit/build/dd47">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        <IfModule mod_authz_host.c>
            Require all granted
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```

so just changed `Require local granted` to `Require all granted`

and working with `localhost` keyword.